# Move cube inside another

Tags: javascript, three.js

In my code i add the `cube2` to the `cube1`:

```
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(255, 255, 255),new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, wireframe: true } ));

  var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 }));

  cube.add(cube2);
  scene.add(cube);
```

Then it looks like this: [image]

But i would like to have the red cude `cube2` at in the corner of my wireframe cube `cube1`:

I tried this: But it didnt worked correctly because it only moved my cube somwhere in the space:

```
  cube2.position = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)
```

So what can i do ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
cube2.position.x = ( 255 - 100 ) / 2;
cube2.position.y = ( 255 - 100 ) / 2;
cube2.position.z = ( 255 - 100 ) / 2;
```

Comment: Now is up to you to understand why :)